# Is there an easy way to set List Item width to text length?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to create a simple navbar with list items that highlight once you mouse-over them. However, by default the list item takes 100% of my page width, so hovering over blank space highlights the list item as well.

Without individually adjusting the width of every item, is there a blanket styling I can apply to make the width of the list item equal to the size of its text?

Here is my navbar, and my stylesheet:

```
<div id="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li>Bio</li>
        <li>News</li>
        <li>Music</li>
        <li>Tour</li>
        <li>Video</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
        <li>Press</li>
        <br>
        <li>Facebook</li>
        <li>Twitter</li>
        <li>Tumblr</li>
        <li>Instagram</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#navbar{
font-family: "Helvetica", "Sans-Serif";
}

#navbar ul li {
list-style-type: none;
}

#navbar ul li:hover {
background-color:#B2322B;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`display: inline-block` should work

Comment: Both answers worked; what bothered me about this was I suspected that text being defined as inline had something to do with this, but when I used display: block it still had a default size. Any idea why that is?